# Jquery Converting a string to Integer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting value using jquery text() mehtod. I want to calculate the SUM of this value with some other value that is a number. I am getting a NaN retun now. code is something like this
I have the value in my page like this `<p id="typeinfo2">445</p>`, value coming dynamically

```
var oldtotal = parseInt($('#typeInfo2').text(), 10);    
var xtra = 75;
var newtotal =  oldtotal  + xtra;
```

alert(newtotal) gives me a NaN. I have already tried with  - Number(oldtotal) + Number(xtra)

Comment: try this syntax `parseInt($('#typeInfo2').text(), 10) || 0`

Comment: @ Kartikeya -  now I am getting 0 from oldtotal

Comment: don't forget to wrap your jquery code inside `$(function(){})` block.

Comment: @SalihK Might be you want to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599952/jquery-converting-a-string-to-integer/28600032#28600032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. id of p tag is `typeinfo2` and not `typeInfo2`:

```
var oldtotal = parseInt($('#typeinfo2').text(), 10);
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling mistake

Change Id `typeInfo2` to `typeinfo2` in your `jQuery` code.

```
var oldtotal = parseInt($('#typeinfo2').text(), 10);
```

```js
var oldtotal = parseInt($('#typeinfo2').text(), 10);    
var xtra = 75;
var newtotal =  oldtotal  + xtra;
alert(newtotal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="typeinfo2">445</p>
```